# When to use ST_Transform and when to use ST_SetSRID in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I'm new to writing postgis queries and I still get confused when writing queries where I have `geom` vs. a projected version of `geom`. My queries end up being a mess and I run into the error that goes something like `conflicting SRID`.

I feel like, mentally, I don't know when to solve it with ST_Transform and when to use ST_SetSRID.

Answer (score 3):

Seems I'm not the only one confused on this. Postgis' website had this article from many years ago now:

#### ST_Transform and ST_SetSRID: To project or not to project?

People often get confused between the ST_Transform and ST_SetSRID functions.

ST_SetSRID doesn’t change the coordinates but adds meta data to state what spatial reference system the coordinate actually are. If you stamped your WGS 84 long lat data as a meter based projection. Guess what? Its still long lat. A spade by any other name is still a spade so don’t use ST_SetSRID and expect to magically get meter coordinates.

ST_Transform is used to change the underlying coordinates from a known spatial reference system to another known spatial reference system.

source: https://postgis.net/2013/08/30/st_transform-and-st_setsrid-to-project-or-not-to-project/

Answer (score 1):

If the coordinates of the geometry already represent the correct spatial reference system, but it is not yet classified as such, use ST_SetSRID.

If you need to change the actual geometry to reflect a certain spatial reference system, use ST_Transform.

From the docs: "ST_Transform actually changes the coordinates of a geometry from one spatial reference system to another, while ST_SetSRID() simply changes the SRID identifier of the geometry." (https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html)